# How to preview xml drawable in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xml-drawable

I know that is possible to preview xml drawables in Android Studio but I wonder if there is a way to preview them in Visual Studio instead of going back and forth between Android Studio and Visual Studio. Any tips?

Comment: I don't think the visual studio previewer can load a drawable it only works with layouts as of now so your best bet is Android studio itself or there are also some websites available that give you a preview i.e. if you do not want to install Android studio or if it is taking too much time to load!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way right now to view XML drawables directly by themselves in Visual Studio for now.

But, since you can view Android AXML Layout files in Visual Studio, so you can view the usage of those XML drawables in your layout files. For example, I am able to see drawables I created for circles around numbers within my layout AXML file